# COUNT with case statement not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following ouput from my query:

```
{
    "player_first_name": "Albano",
    "player_last_name": "Aleksi",
    "yellow_cards": "14",
    "orange_cards": "0",
    "red_cards": "1",
    "points": "15",
    "player_id": "286635"
}
```

as you can see  the player have 14 yellow cards, 1 red cards and 0 orange cards.

I want calculate the "point" earned by this playern counting each card in the following way:

- yellow card: 1 point
- orange card: 2 point
- red card: 3 point

so the final result should be: 17

I tried to count the total of the points in the following way:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT
    p.first_name AS player_first_name,
    p.last_name AS player_last_name,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN c.card_id = 1 THEN 1
      END) AS yellow_cards,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.card_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS orange_cards,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN c.card_id = 3 THEN 1
      END) AS red_cards,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN c.card_id = 1 THEN 1
      WHEN c.card_id = 2 THEN 2
      WHEN c.card_id = 3 THEN 3
      END) AS points,
    p.id AS player_id
    FROM `match` m
    INNER JOIN player_cards c ON c.match_id = m.id
    INNER JOIN player p ON c.player_id = p.id
    WHERE m.round_id = :round_id
    GROUP BY p.id
    ORDER BY points DESC, player_last_name ASC");
```

as you can see I have the following statement:

```
 COUNT(CASE
      WHEN c.card_id = 1 THEN 1
      WHEN c.card_id = 2 THEN 2
      WHEN c.card_id = 3 THEN 3
      END) AS points,
```

the card id correspond the id of the color, so:

- 1: yellow card
- 2: orange card
- 3: red card

why the toal is incorrect?

*UPDATE*

Expected output:

```
{
    "player_first_name": "Albano",
    "player_last_name": "Aleksi",
    "yellow_cards": "14",
    "orange_cards": "0",
    "red_cards": "1",
    "points": "17",
    "player_id": "286635"
}
```

as you can see `points` is `17` because we have 14 yellow cards (each yellow card is worth 1 point), and we have 1 red card, each red card is worth 3 point, so: 14 + 3 = 17. But I get 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
COUNT(CASE
      WHEN c.card_id = 1 THEN 1
      WHEN c.card_id = 2 THEN 2
      WHEN c.card_id = 3 THEN 3
      END) AS points,
```

with

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN c.card_id = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN c.card_id = 2 THEN 2
    WHEN c.card_id = 3 THEN 3
    END) AS points,
```

because with count you just count while you want the sum really. If you *count* the numbers 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 you get fifteen, if you *add them up* you get seventeen.

However, there is obviously a card table the `card_id` refers to. This `card` table should naturally contain the value of the card. So join with the cards table and use

```
SUM(card.value)
```

instead of the above.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I hope you follow the advice of storing the points value in the cards table. As to the other answers: They work just as fine provided only IDs 1, 2, and 3 exist and ID 1 values 1, ID 2 values 2 and ID 3 values 3. So when you say they don't work for you, you probably made a mistake with explaining your data or setting up the sample query.

Comment: I don't see how the logic in this answer is any different from the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Since you just want to sum the numerical value of the card to get the total, then just use `SUM(card_id)` instead of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    p.first_name AS player_first_name,
    p.last_name AS player_last_name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.card_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS yellow_cards,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.card_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS orange_cards,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.card_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS red_cards,
    SUM(c.card_id) AS points,
    p.id AS player_id
FROM match m
INNER JOIN player_cards c
    ON c.match_id = m.id
INNER JOIN player p
    ON c.player_id = p.id
WHERE
    m.round_id = :round_id
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    points DESC, player_last_name;
```

Your PHP code should then look like this:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare();
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $red = $row["red_cards"];
    $yel = $row["yellow_cards"];
    $orange = $row["orange_cards"];
    $points = $row["points"];
}
```

Comment: mm maybe I said that badly. If you look at the query, each card have a different points value (by color), that's why I used a case statement, because I need to evaluate the card id and then assign the correct points to sum

Comment: Edit your question and show us the real data.  What I wrote above works with your current data.

Comment: @popop Your update doesn't change anything.  You just want to sum the numerical face value of the penalty card.

Comment: the value of each card is difference against the id, the id rapresent the color of the card, based on that id, I can set the points, with your code I'll get 15, that's wrong

Comment: Did you even bother to try my code?  Is `14 + 3 = 15`?  No, it's not.  It's equal to 17.

Comment: Then I question your data, not my query.

Comment: The data have no problems, and I don't understand why a simple sum should be sufficient against a card.id evaluation, maybe you could explain better why your query should work 'cause for me is unclear

Comment: Either you 1) didn't copy my query correctly, 2) didn't refresh your PHP server side code, or 3) don't have the data you think you did.

Comment: None ot the three, I think that the problem of logic is that we are not evaluating the value of the cards but simply adding up.

Comment: Did you also update your PHP as I asked?  Check my updated answer.  Your code should match this exactly.

Comment: I get red: 1, yellow: 14, orange = 0, points = 16, again, point must be 17

Comment: @popup double check the card IDs match what you expect then to be. It looks like red card id = 2 and yellow id=3 (or could be 0)

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to count the points by query the cards from the database, save it in variables and then count them all without any inline `CASE` statements in SQL. Make a simple query where you get each player's red, orange and yellow cards and then count them as in the example.

```
// The query to get the cards, name etc.
$sql = "SELECT
p.first_name AS player_first_name,
p.last_name AS player_last_name,
c.card_id = 1 THEN 1 AS yellow_cards
c.card_id = 2 THEN 2 AS orange_cards
c.card_id = 3 THEN 3 AS red_cards
p.id AS player_id
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN player_cards c ON c.match_id = m.id
INNER JOIN player p ON c.player_id = p.id
WHERE m.round_id = round_id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY points DESC, player_last_name ASC";

// Prepared statement to get the cards as variables and then count the points
$stmt = $connection->prepare();
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $red = $row["red_cards"];
    $yel = $row["yellow_cards"];
    $orange = $row["orange_cards"];
    $points = $red * 3 + $orange * 2 + $yel;
}
```

Please note that I used prepared statements in the example and the `$connection` variable covers the mySQL connection to the server.

Comment: I prefer to evaluate this in query without adding more code, thanks for the answer anyway +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all your `count` with `sum` and retry.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, `count()` counts the number of *non*-`NULL` results.  Hence, `0` is as non-`NULL` as any other value.

But, MySQL also offers a convenient shortcut that doesn't use `CASE`.  Boolean expressions are treated as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So:

```
SELECT p.first_name AS player_first_name, p.last_name AS player_last_name,
       SUM( c.card_id = 1 ) AS yellow_cards,
       SUM( c.card_id = 2 ) AS orange_cards,
       SUM( c.card_id = 3 ) AS red_cards,
       SUM( CASE WHEN c.card_id IN (1, 2, 3) THEN c.card_id ELSE 0 END) AS points,
       p.id AS player_id
FROM `match` m INNER JOIN
     player_cards c
     ON c.match_id = m.id INNER JOIN
     player p ON c.player_id = p.id
WHERE m.round_id = :round_id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY points DESC, player_last_name ASC;
```

If the only allowed `card_id`s are 0, 1, 2, and 3, then the points calculation can be simplified to:

```
       SUM( c.card_id ) AS points,
```

Comment: Gordon, the problem is not the sum, the problem is the value to sum. As you can see from my update I don't need to sum each card with 1, but I need to sum each card with the correspond value. So yellow card is worh: 1, red is worth 2. Now if I use the sum I'll get as total 15 because I have 14 yellow cards and 1 red card, but I need to get 17 because 1 red card is worth 3 not 1, it's all clear?

Comment: @pop . . . That is the *points* calculation and both versions in this answer do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code is:

```
SUM(c.card_id) AS points,
```

If you don't want to depend on `card_id` having certian values, then this is the next simplest:

```
SUM((c.card_id = 1) + 2 * (c.card_id = 2) + 3 * (c.card_id = 3))
```

This works because in MySQL `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.